# Create new Arrays from linkedHashMap with keys and values separately

Tags: java, arrays, linkedhashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap and I am trying to split its keys and values and refer to specific key in the keyset or value in valueset. For ex.
Lets say I have the folowing LinkedHashMap:

4 | 2

3 | 1

I want a function to return 1, which is  a value at index 1 in the set with values or return 2 for index = 0.
And with another function I want to get 3 as value with index 1 in key values.
So basically from the LinkedHashMap create an Array with only values/ keys and then look for some given place in this array.
My code looks as follow:

```
    public static Integer getLHMValue(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) { 
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> valueSet = lhm.entrySet();
        Integer[] valueArray = valueSet.toArray(new Integer[valueSet.size()]);
        Integer value = valueArray[index];
        return value;
    }

    public static Integer getLHMKey(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) { 
        Set<Integer> keySet = lhm.keySet();
        Integer[] keyArray = keySet.toArray(new Integer[keySet.size()]);
        Integer key = keyArray[index];
        return key;
}
```

Though, I get java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry in:
Integer[] keyArray = valueSet.toArray(new Integer[valueSet.size()]);.
Any ideas?

Comment: First off, this will not work with a generic `Map`, as many maps are not insertion-order based (`TreeMap` is sorted, `HashMap` is unordered, etc). Lastly, it appears you merely want to get the key/value pair at index `index` within the map, which can be achieved via using an `Iterator` over `lhm.entrySet()` while tracking the index with an incrementing `int` (which the internal documentation seems to suggest is the "fastest" solution). **That all said**, this feels like a dirty solution/approach. What are you trying to achieve by doing this? Beware the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I need to check if there is the same value in this hashmap at position 0 and 1. Moreover I need to multiply key and entry by some specific value

Comment: Yes, but why do you need those values by the index? For what purpose is the code in your example being used for? Think of the bigger picture overall (your problem, rather than your solution).

Comment: That is for a poker handrank calculation. My solution works in such way, that I create LHM with rank of the card as key and number of its apperance as value. Then I check the first value to pick which players have better cards. If they have two pairs values will be 2 2 . Thats why I try to refer to some concrete places in the key and value sets of this linkedhashmap.

Comment: I see, and while that solution will work, I still think you might be better served with some proper definitions of classes (e.g. `Card`, `Rank`, `Hand`, `Hand#getScore`, etc.) which would allow you to forgo the muckery of dealing with indices and numbers in this manner. But that would fundamentally change your question at this point.

Comment: Exactly. I know there are other solutions for it, but I couldnt find too much for this solution and couldnt solve it by maself either. This question came more from curiosity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the entrySet would be needed to first have an array of `Map.Entry`s. Keeping such an array for both methods would be faster.

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> entries = new ArrayList<>(lhm.entrySet());

public static long getLHMValue(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) { 
    return entries.get(index).getValue();
}

public static int getLHMKey(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) { 
    return entries.get(index).getKey();
}
```

There is no efficient solution if you do it directly, and so it is not advisable to offer these functions to access key and value.

```
public static Long getLHMValue(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) { 
    return lhm.entrySet().stream()
        .map(Map.Entry<Integer, Long>::getValue)
        .skip(index)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(IndexOutOfBoundsException::new);
}

public static Integer getLHMKey(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) { 
    return lhm.entrySet().stream()
        .map(Map.Entry<Integer, Long>::getKey)
        .skip(index)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(IndexOutOfBoundsException::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getLHMValue` the problem is your array creation:

```
Integer[] keyArray = valueSet.toArray(new Integer[valueSet.size()]);
```

because `valueSet` is `Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>`.
Modify your initialisation of `valueSet` to

```
Collection<Long> valueSet = lhm.values();
```

But now you get the problem that `Collection` does not ensure any order.

Btw: your values are `Long` so you also should return `Long`

Comment: I need it sorted :/

Comment: I had a look at the implementation of `LinkedHashMap#values`. This results in a 'linked' set which is sorted. But as Rogue mentioned in the comments, your method accepts all `Map`s, also unsorted versions.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

Firstly, it's highly advisable to favor Collections over Arrays, because collections can offer you behavior and arrays have a type-safety pitfall due to their covariant behavior (refer to *"Effective Java"* by Joshua Bloch, item "Prefer lists to arrays").

Since ***the map is always the same*** (clarification provided by OP in the comments) you can declare a list as a `stitic final` variable, dump map entries into it and access this list from your methods.

That would allow to avoid performing unnecessary iteration each method call which costs **O(n)** time.

```
public static final Map<Integer, Long> LHM = // initializing the map
public static final List<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> ENTRIES = new ArrayList<>(LHM.entrySet());
```

With that change your methods would work in constant time **O(1)** instead of linear.

```
public static Long getLHMValue(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) {
    
    return ENTRIES.get(index).getValue();
}

public static Integer getLHMKey(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) {

    return ENTRIES.get(index).getKey();
}
```

---

You can introduce a variable that would represent the current index.

Then iterate over the entries until the target index is reached.

Return the *key/value* from the target entry

```
public static Long getLHMValue(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= lhm.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    Map.Entry<Integer, Long> result = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry: lhm.entrySet()) {
        if (i == index) result = entry;
        i++;
    }
    return result.getValue();
}
```

Alternativelly, you can use Java 11 method [`Collection.toArray(IntFunction<T[]>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) or it's sibling [`Collection.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) available with earlier versions.

```
public static Long getLHMValue(Map<Integer, Long> lhm, int index) {

    return lhm.values().toArray(Long[]::new)[index]; // or lhm.values().toArray(new Long[0])[index];
}
```

Comment: That was actually my first solution, thanks! Now I see that it may be the best one. I actually was certain that it may be done easier.

Comment: @AmandaStein Clarify please you're dialing with different maps at each method call or the map is always the same (encapsulated inside a class)?

Comment: always the same

Comment: @AmandaStein Then don't need to parse it as an argument. You can dump the entries into a `List` declared as a `stitic final` variable and access this list from your methods.

Comment: Is this Collection.toArray keeping the order?

Comment: @AmandaStein Yes, but you don't need it. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: @AmandaStein See the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248233/discussion-between-amanda-stein-and-alexander-ivanchenko).